# How to import an ancient Android project with NO GRADLE WHATSOEVER into today's Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, import

At first glance, you might think that this question has been answered a few times on line. However, every article I found here and elsewhere had to do with importing an old Android project into today's Android Studio where one or more gradle config files already exist in one or more places in the project's code tree.

In my case, however, I have a 9-year-old Android project that I want to work on within today's Android studio, and my project contains ***no gradle-related files whatsoever !!!***

I believe I used either IntelliJ or Eclipse to build this project back when I was originally working on it in 2014.

Is there any way to import an old Android project which is ***totally devoid of anything to do with gradle*** into today's Android Studio and then successfully build it for a modern version of Android (Android 11 or later)?

I realize that I'll probably have to make some code changes in order to get the old (kitkat-based) code to run properly under Android 11 or later. I'm not asking about such code changes. What I simply want to know is how to get today's Android Studio to successfully import my ancient project. ***Then*** I will be able to make the necessary code changes.

Please forgive me if my online searches have overlooked an answer to this question. If so, a pointer to such an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions.

Here is a listing of all the files and directories in my project ...

```
    AndroidManifest.xml
    project.properties
    bin/
    bin/AndroidManifest.xml
    bin/classes
    bin/classes/us
    bin/classes/us/potam
    bin/classes/us/potam/hippo
    bin/classes/us/potam/hippo/experimental
    bin/res
    src/
    src/us
    src/us/potam
    src/us/potam/hippo
    src/us/potam/hippo/experimental
    src/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ThirdPartyBase64.java
    src/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSDBHelper.java
    src/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSBootReceiver.java
    src/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSMessage.java
    src/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSHandler.java
    src/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSObserver.java
    src/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSService.java
    src/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSDataSource.java
    src/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSMainActivity.java
    src/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalUtils.java
    libs/
    proguard-project.txt
    gen/
    gen/us
    gen/us/potam
    gen/us/potam/hippo
    gen/us/potam/hippo/experimental
    gen/us/potam/hippo/experimental/BuildConfig.java
    gen/us/potam/hippo/experimental/R.java
    out/
    out/production
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/BuildConfig.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ThirdPartyBase64.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSService.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/R$drawable.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSMainActivity$1.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalUtils.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSDBHelper.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ThirdPartyBase64$1.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/R$layout.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSBootReceiver.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/R$dimen.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSMainActivity.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/R$id.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSHandler.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ThirdPartyBase64$OutputStream.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSHandler$1.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/R.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSMessage.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/R$attr.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSDataSource.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/R$string.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ExperimentalSMSObserver.class
    out/production/ExperimentalSMSTrigger/us/potam/hippo/experimental/ThirdPartyBase64$InputStream.class
    .idea/
    .idea/workspace.xml
    .idea/misc.xml
    .idea/runConfigurations
    .idea/runConfigurations/ExperimentalSMS.xml
    .idea/.gitignore
    .idea/modules.xml
    .classpath
    res/
    res/values-v14
    res/layout
    res/layout/main_activity_screen.xml
    res/values-v11
    res/drawable-hdpi
    res/drawable-hdpi/experimental.png
    res/drawable
    res/drawable/experimental.png
    res/drawable-xhdpi
    res/drawable-xhdpi/experimental.png
    res/values
    res/values/dimens.xml
    res/values/strings.xml
    res/drawable-xxhdpi
    res/drawable-xxhdpi/experimental.png
    res/drawable-mdpi
    res/drawable-mdpi/experimental.png
    res/values-w820dp
    res/values-w820dp/dimens.xml
    res/drawable-ldpi
    res/drawable-ldpi/experimental.png
    .project
    .settings/
    .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    ExperimentalSMSTrigger.iml
    assets/
```

Comment: What's wrong with creating a new empty Android project, copying over the src/ res/ directories, manifest and gitignore and try to build it. You'll have to make some changes to the new gradle file but as it is an old project its probably worth reviewing dependencies, etc.

Comment: I was trying something like that, but I got lost trying to figure out what to do with the new gradle file. Is there perhaps some way to auto-generate an appropriate gradle file given the src/ and res/ items?

Comment: assets folder too. The locations may have changed so it is better if you move by dragging the content of each parent folder (src, res, assets) to proper Android Studio folder in "Android" mode. There should not be any special problem with the gradle files. It is the same as if you were writing all this code now to the new project. I think you would have to be more specific describing what goes wrong. This link may help too https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Comment: Thank you! I'm in the process of trying this. The newly created empty project does not contain any "assets" folder. Where in the project directory tree for the empty project should the "assets" folder from the old project get copied to?

Comment: Never mind! My original "assets" directory is empty, anyway. And I found the "assets" directory for the new project: `app/build/intermediates/assets`.  And I followed your suggestion, and the app is running! I didn't even need to change any of the code.  I have some small feature changes to make, but now I can go forward. I'll put an Answer in place here.  Thank you again to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the advice of @Morrison-Chang and @Doron-Ben-Ari, and I got the old project loaded and running within today's Android Studio!

Here's all I ended up doing ...

1. I created an empty project in Android Studio with the same name as my old project: `ExperimentalSMSTrigger`, and I specified the package name that I use in my old project.
2. I copied all of the `*.java` files from the old project -- including `ExperimentalSMSMainActivity.java` -- into the same directory where `MainActivity.java` is resident in the new project.
3. I deleted the `MainActivity.java` file in the new project.
4. I replaced the `res` and `AndroidManifest.xml` items in the new project with the corresponding items in the old project.
5. I changed the names of all references to `MainActivity` in the new project to `ExperimentalSMSMainActivity`.

I then did a "build" and a "run", and it's working!

It turns out that I didn't have to do anything with gradle.

Now, I just have some feature enhancements to write, and the resulting app will be able to run under Android 11 or later Android versions.

Thank you again to both of you for your help!